# js remove only default message onclick, not text a user inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea, jtextarea

Afternoon all,

In need of some technical advice from the masters... I know the function to remove the default message on click from a form, but the problem that's occuring is that after a user has initially clicked in the message area (to remove the default), if they then click in the message area again, it removes what they've written!! I guess an example would be if they noticed a spelling mistake or need to change part of their message.

There must be a way to solve this?

The code for the text area is:

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="55" tabindex="9"   onclick="this.value=''">
  <?php if(isset($error)) {echo $message;} else {echo "Please use this area for any other information about your enquiry";}?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/bkNBa/)

HTML:

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="55" tabindex="9">default message</textarea>
```

JavaScript place within the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var defaultMsg = document.getElementById("message").value;

    function init() {
        var mytextarea = document.getElementById('message');

        mytextarea.onblur = function() {
            if (this.value == '') this.value = defaultMsg;
        }

        mytextarea.onfocus = function() {
            if (this.value == defaultMsg) this.value = '';
        }
    }

    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi kyj112 - I removed the onclick function and added:
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function init() {
    var mytextarea = document.getElementById('message');

    mytextarea.onblur = function() {
        if (this.value == '') this.value = 'default message';
    }

    mytextarea.onfocus = function() {
        if (this.value == 'default message') this.value = '';
    }
}

window.onload = init;
</script>

Now though the message doesn't disappear on click at all

Comment: did it work for you? does your textarea have "default message" within it to start with?

Comment: Yes - <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="55" tabindex="9">Please use this area for any other information about your enquiry</textarea>

i've double checked the javascript that you sent (see reply above), which I've put just below the text area html but nothing is happening. Sorry!

Comment: @user456492 i have a feeling the default messages aren't matching let me edit my answer again to augment that. Try the edited code.

Comment: @user456492 it works on the jsfiddle. not sure what is the issue. how are you attaching the JavaScript?  can you post your entire code after edit? make sure you dont' have another element w/ id of "message"

Comment: @user456492 put the `<script>` in `<head>` section not below the textarea

Comment: Thanks kj for your help - all sorted now from offex. However, I see you're a php coder, would you mind helping me with a php question? I could email you if easier...

Comment: what's your email address? essentially my form isn't pulling up the error message if something isn't selected (sends to the thank you page, regardless whether they've completed every element or not). Plus it's not adding the fields to the db - everything is set up and was working, it must just be something small...

Comment: @Motley9735 u can twitter me or facebook me, but i prefer it posted on stackoverflow so i can get some rep and etc lhehehe check my profile for twitter and facebook

Answer (score 1):

After the initial onclick you will need to remove the onclick attribute from the textarea using something like this:

```
document.getElementById('message').onclick = null;
```

You could change the onclick to call a function that does the `this.value = ''` and then removes the onclick.

Edit:

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="55" tabindex="9"   onclick="removeDefaultText(this)">
  <?php if(isset($error)) {echo $message;} else {echo "Please use this area for any other information about your enquiry";}?>
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function removeDefaultText(el){
  el.value='';
  el.onclick=null;
}
</script>
```

Comment: sorry offex, I'm still learning my way with this - would the snippet of code you gave above replace the onclick="this.value=''" which I'm currently using?

Comment: Hi offex - thank you so much - however this sitll doesn't work. The on click function works however after then typing in a message, if you click anywhere in the text area the whole message disappears

Comment: @user456492 from what i understand, you want to the user to be able to edit the message after they've typed something in the textarea instead of wiping it again, correct?

Comment: correct kjy112 - e.g. if the user wants to alter the message - at present if they click anywhere within the message they've written (to amend it) it wipes the whole message

Comment: @user456492 please take a look at my answer. basically remove what you curently hvae within the textarea and attach the JS function within a header `<script type="javascript/text">`

Comment: Apologies offex - must've been doing something slightly wrong, this worked. Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 1):

What you *probably* want is this, right?

- When the page first loads and there's no user-supplied value, the "Please use" message is shown.
- When the textarea gets focus, the "Please use" message should go away. (Perhaps you want to wait until something is typed; whatever.)
- When the textarea *loses* focus, if the user has left behind an empty `<textarea>` then the "Please use" message should come back.
- When the form is submitted, something has to check to see if the `<textarea>` is still empty (showing the "Please use" message) and if so disable it or clear the value.

What I'd do is have the "focus" and "blur" handlers maintain a state indicator to explicitly track the state of the element, instead of relying on doing a text comparison to your "Please use" message.  Exactly how you do that would depend on the way you're writing event handlers in general, but it might look like this:

```
function setupTextareaHandlers() {
  var txta = document.getElementById("yourTextArea");
  var empty = !txta.value;
  txta.onfocus = function() {
    if (empty) txta.value = '';
  };
  txta.onblur = function() {
    if (!txta.value) {
      empty = true;
      txta.value = 'Please use ... ';
    }
  };
}
```

You would probably also set up your submit handler in there too.

Answer (score 1):

a simple working script

```
<textarea name="message" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
Put anything for default value here
</textarea>
```

just lernaed a few minutes ago X)

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/SRYLg/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="55" tabindex="9"     onclick="javascript:if(this.value='default.value') this.value =''">
  <?php if(isset($error)) {echo $message;} else {echo "Please use this area for any other information about your enquiry";}?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: There's no need to put "javascript:" at the beginning of values for "onfoo" attributes - in fact it's treated by the interpreter as a statement label :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one, but this never worked - the on click still occurred after the initial on click (if that makes sense)